# Including a .pri file in multiple .pro project file with different relative paths

Tags: qt, qmake

Hi I have some files in a dir called COMMON_SRC and a .pri file for these src files : Common.pri
and two projects in diffrent relative paths to common files.
I wanna use only one Common.pri file.
Can anyone help me?
Can I use some variable in each .pro file which tells the Common.pri file the relative path to project?
something like $$PWD ?

Answer (score 2):

`_PRO_FILE_PWD_` is what you want ([docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#pro-file-pwd)).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, assume You have a project tree like below:

```
 /
 ├─common_src
 ├─test
 └─lib
```

and you have `common.pri` in the `common_src` folder which points to source files. Imagine you like to include sources in `test` and `lib` projects.
So, change files path in `common.pri` in order to include current path as below:

```
SOURCES += \
        $$PWD/document.cpp 

HEADERS += \
        $$PWD/document.h
```

now, include common sources in other projects as this:

*lib.pro:*

```
#...

include(../common_src/common.pri)

#...
```

**This trick causes to included path be interpreted as relative to the current project path.**